# Using imparfait vs passé composé in a sentence with "quand"

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, passé-composé, imparfait

I have the following sentence:

> Quand j'avais 9 ans, je mangerais/'ai mangé le fromage habituellement

If you translate this to english, it would make sense to use the passé composé form of manger; however, I am also aware that you should use imparfait for any repeated action.

How should I conjugate manger?

Comment: “mangerais” is **not** imparfait, it's conditionnel présent.

Comment: It would be interresting to know what exactly you want to convey. For example, if you simply wanted to tell you used to eat cheese as a kid but not anymore as a grown up, I would drop "habituellement": "Quand j'étais petit, je mangeais du fromage"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You confuse *présent du conditionnel (mangerais)* and *imparfait de l'indicatif (mangeais*).

Moreover, both *le* and *habituellement* are odd here.

Something idiomatic would be:

> Quand j'avais neuf ans, j'avais l'habitude de manger du fromage.

or, if you insist to use *habituellement*:

> Quand j'avais neuf ans, je mangeais habituellement du fromage.

Comment: My bad, that was a typo on my part

Comment: Bien que correcte, cette formulation me donne l'impression d'appeler un complément supplémentaire :  tous les jours, le mercredi, avec mon grand-père,... peu importe, mais sans doute n'est-ce qu'une impression.